# CircularProgressIndicator code in appBar not working

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In the dropDownButton in the appBar, I want the progress bar to appear when the item is changed. I wrote a code for this, but the progress Bar is not coming.

```
    class arayuzEkrani extends StatefulWidget {
  const arayuzEkrani({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _arayuzEkraniState createState() => _arayuzEkraniState();
}

class _arayuzEkraniState extends State<arayuzEkrani> {
  Map<String, String> countryFlags = {
    "usa": " İngilizce",
    "almanca": " Almanca",
  };

  List <subjectInfo> subjects = [subjectInfo("Selamlaşma", "assets/selamlasma.png"), subjectInfo("Hayvanlar", "assets/hayvanlar.png"), subjectInfo("Teknoloji", "assets/teknoloji.png"), subjectInfo("Meyve Sebze", "assets/meyvesebze.png"), subjectInfo("Meslekler", "assets/meslekler.png")];

// "Selamlaşma", "Hayvanlar", "Teknoloji", "Meyve ve Sebze", "Meslekler"
  var defaultFlag = " İngilizce";
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.public,
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 27,
        ),
        title: const Text(
          "Kelime Öğren",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          DropdownButton<String>(
            items: countryFlags
                .map((country, flag) {
                  return MapEntry(
                      country,
                      DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: flag,
                        
                        child: Text(flag, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                      ));
                })
                .values
                .toList(),

            value: defaultFlag,
            onChanged: (String? country) {

  
              setState(() {
                defaultFlag = country!;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

I want the progress bar with the changed option in the dropDownButton to come. What is the problem? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
bool isCountryChanged = false; // for update UI when country changed.

appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    leading: const Icon(
      Icons.public,
      color: Colors.black,
      size: 27,
    ),
    title: const Text(
      "Kelime Öğren",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    elevation: 0,
    actions: [
      DropdownButton<String>(
        items: countryFlags
            .map((country, flag) {
              return MapEntry(
                  country,
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: flag,    
                    child: Text(flag, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                  ));
            })
            .values
            .toList(),
        value: defaultFlag,
        onChanged: (String? country) {
          setState(() {
            defaultFlag = country!;
           isCountryChanged = true; });
           //  display circular indicator for 1 second.
         Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () async {
             setState(() {
               isCountryChanged = false; });             
                  });
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
  body:isCountryChanged? CircularProgressIndicator( 
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
          strokeWidth: 5,
          );   : // do stuff
```

Comment: Hi, It was constantly loading. https://imgur.com/a/VcxZl5T

Comment: Updated. Pl check again.

Comment: How can we make it stop after a few seconds? There is a code to stop in the code you gave, but it does not stop. Also, I want this way of loading, to appear in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Need a ternary operator which can control your data is ready or not if not  CircularProgressIndicator() will shown at appbar unless you can see your data.For example you can be try to fetch data from db that can be take time or maybe you cant fetch data so in this stuation must be show a progress indicator when data ready progress indicator bar will execute.

```
String? foo;
Future fetchDummy()async{
foo = await dummyData
}

foo !=nul? Text("$foo") : CircularProgressIndicator()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a variable of type duration and then create a function which returns a future builder which is going to await for the duration to finish then display the country but in the mean time will display a circular indicator

Comment: There is a special list. I updated the codes.